# Responsive css is not used when frame is used

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frame

I have a website which is working as expected when resizing my window (responsive css is used) : http://carthera.eu/

But when I'm going on the same website with this url http://carthera.com/ responsive css is not taken into account. 
I have seen that this url is using a frame to display http://carthera.eu.

Do you have any idea why I have this issue ?

Comment: It looks the same to me on Chrome 43, OSX 10.10.
Also, the sidebar (hamburger menu) automatically opens when I resize it on both, and requires 2 clicks to close.

Comment: In .com website is loaded the .eu website. Using src attribute in frame you can specifies the URL of the document to show in a frame.
So the css is loaded with whole document.

Comment: @MarkPolivchuk : sorry, this only happened when you use mobile settings not when resizing the window.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani Is there something to do when you can't change the frame ? (the host is handling this).

Comment: I honestly don't know, but you site look good and works in the same way for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do a 301 redirect to the principal domain name. I had no other solution having no control over the frame.